# RBS installation in clustered DB

Tags: remote-blob-storage

Most of RBS installation scenarios are written for single DB sever instance. If I have cluster with two nodes SPDB1 and SPDB2 (cluster name SPDB - I referenced this name everywhere when I had to provide DB instance name), and I installed RBS on node1 which was active at the time - do I also have to install it on second node, which is passive? If yes, what command should I use?

When second node becomes active and first one passive, will I be able to run RBS maintainer from the first node (because it is installed only there )?